# How to register multiple Consumers using Steeltoe and RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, steeltoe

I am trying to register multiple RabbitMQ's consumers using Steeltoe, but only one is "processing" the messages. For the other consumer I get:

*"Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'myConsumer'"*

Say below are my two consumers:

Consumer #1

```
[EnableBinding(typeof(ISink))]
    public class LoggingConsumer
    {
        [StreamListener(ISink.INPUT)]
        public void Handle(Person person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + person);
        }


    }
```

Consumer #2

```
[EnableBinding(typeof(IEnrollment))]
    public class EnrollmentConsumer
    {
        [StreamListener(IEnrollment.INPUT)]
        public void Handle(Enroll message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + message);
        }


    }
```

How can I register multiple Consumers since only one `.AddStreamServices<LoggingConsumer>();` is allowed in Program.cs?

Thanks!

I have followed the sample provided by Steeltoe to register a Consumer. (https://docs.steeltoe.io/guides/stream/quick-start.html)

Also, if I add the second consumer as ***service.AddStreamBinding();*** it only creates the consumer in RabbitMQ's Queue.

Comment: can you add the main method class/code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanielCCR,
It is possible to subscribe to multiple producers and consumers in a couple of different ways. The simple way is to create one type with an EnableBinding Attribute on it and have multiple input/output destinations inside. See example [here](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/multi-io/Stream/Multi-io2/SampleSinkAndSource.cs).

Alternatively, you can keep these separate but add a few extension methods to add multiple producers/consumers like in this [example](https://%20https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/multi-io/Stream/Multi-io2/Extensions.cs).
which will allow you to do this:

```
builder.Host.AddStreamServices(typeof(SampleSource), typeof(SampleSink));
```